# Generic archive created when updating an existing Mac app?

Tags: macos, xcode4, archive

I've made an update to my existing Mac app and went to archive it.

In Organizer it came up as a new entry and not under the previous releases I had. This new entry appears generic, ie. no app icon, no version or identifier info, just the name of the app came through. What happened? How do I troubleshoot?

In the update I added a UTI and also copied a plug-in into my bundle. Could those things have something to do with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it. My problem was related to dependency targets. Here's the solution:
http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2429

(Excerpt added 2012-12-18; see blog post for screenshots and background info)

> 1. … Select dependent project(s) in the Project Navigator
> 2. Find “Skip Install” and set to YES.
> 3. If you have more dependent project, repeat these steps for all of them (i.e. at static library projects).
>
> The app is expected to be deployed so do not change the Skip Install’s No to YES there. Change at the dependent projects only.